# The other additional variable in the View of Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({

  options: {
    "theList": []
  },

  initialize: function() {
    console.log(this.options.theList.length);
    this.options.theList.push("xxx");
  }

});

// other place:

var view1 = new TestView();
// the console result will be 0

var view2 = new TestView();
// the console result will be 1 !!!

var view3 = new TestView();
// the console result will be 2 !!!!!!
```

...

Why? I think it will just console 0 every time that I `new` the `TestView` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside the `extend` call will be attached to the view's prototype. That means that your `options` will be shared by all instances of `TestView` so each time you:

```
this.options.theList.push("xxx");
```

you're pushing a string onto the exact same array that all instances are sharing/referencing through the prototype.

If you want separate `options` for each instance, set it up in the view's constructor:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.options.theList = [ ];
    console.log(this.options.theList.length);
    this.options.theList.push("xxx");
  }
});
```

Comment: But I console the view in the Chrome, the `option` attribute don't placed in the __proto__ attribute, it's just out there.